# How to use any stream on wstring to extract data

Tags: c++, string, stream, stringstream

I was reading data from a file using `wifstream`

the txt file looks like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
2,3,4,5,6,7,8
...
...
```

each number is an id I needed for my program and comma is the separator
Here is my code

```
wifstream inputFile(FILE_PATH);
if(inputFile)
{
    wchar_t regex;
    int id;
    while(inputFile)
    {
        inputFile>>id;
        inputFile.get(regex);

        cout << id << ", ";                         
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

This code works perfectly fine, until I change the reading scheme in which a single line is read at a time, I wanted to do something similar on the line so I can read data from the line while the buffer of the stream pops the data once it's been read like above. But I can't get it working.
Here is my code

```
    wifstream inputFile(FILE_PATH);
    wstring line;
    if(inputFile)
    {
        while(!inputFile.eof())
        {

            std::getline(inputFile, line);

            for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i+=2)
            {
                int id;
                wchar_t regex;
                wstringstream(line)>>id; // doesn't work as it keep getting the same number
                wstringstream(line).get(regex);

                cout << id << ", ";
            }
            cout << endl;

        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
```

I think the reason it doesn't work is that I'm not using a stream properly and it keeps reading the id at the very first index and never progress no matter how many times I use `>>` (probably not the right way to use it anyways), I also tried `wifstream`, no use either.

How am I supposed to get around with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating the `wstringstream` each time you use it. Move the creation outside the loop:

```
wifstream inputFile(FILE_PATH);
wstring line;
if(inputFile)
{
    while(!inputFile.eof())
    {

        std::getline(inputFile, line);

        wstringstream istring(line);
        for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i+=2)
        {
            int id;
            wchar_t regex;
            istring>>id;
            istring.get(regex);

            cout << id << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl;

    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```